# RANDBETWEEN(1,11) but not 6?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to use RANDBETWEEN(1,11) but omit 6 and then drag it down. I don't know how to keep excel from including 6 as a random result?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

maybe something like this:

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),RANDBETWEEN(1,5),RANDBETWEEN(7,11))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I'll give it a try. Can I ask, why did you not just do =CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,5),RANDBETWEEN(7,11))?

Comment: it's a syntax of `CHOOSE(index_num, value1, [value2], ...)` - first argument is an index of returning values. If `RANDBETWEEN(1,2)=1` we evaluate `RANDBETWEEN(1,5)`, otherwise, if `RANDBETWEEN(1,2)=2` we evaluate `RANDBETWEEN(7,11)`

Answer (score 2):

Try,

=choose(randbetween(1,10),1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11)

As you can see 6 is not included in the list of random numbers.

Comment: This answer is better than accepted because it is more general. It will also work for two unequal ranges like <1,5> and <7,8> `choose(randbetween(1,7),1,2,3,4,5,7,8)` will return each number with the same probability =1/7. On the other hand `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),RANDBETWEEN(1,5),RANDBETWEEN(7,8))` will return numbers <1,5> with p=1/10 and <7,8> with p=1/4 which means second range will show up more freakwently.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion just use simple code:

```
 1. step1: 
 2. a = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 11) 
 3. If a = 6 Then GoTo step1
```

After that You will never receive 6 as result

Answer (score -1):

You can use RANDBETWEEN(1,11) and add 1 to the result if the result is 6 or greater.

Disclaimer: I don't know about the actual syntax for that since I haven't worked with excel for quite some time...

Comment: it's not actually working, since your idea is to use something like this: `=IF(RANDBETWEEN(1,11)=6,RANDBETWEEN(1,11)+1,RANDBETWEEN(1,11))`, but there are _three different rand number_ and if first is 6, second could be easily 5 and formula could evaluates to `=IF(6=6,5+1,8)` what gives you still 6

Comment: In addition to what @simoco said, if the result of `RANDBETWEEN` is `11`, then the actual result will be `12`.

Comment: Sorry, I mean RANDBETWEEN(1,10). The `CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),RANDBETWEEN(1,5),RANDBETWEEN(7,11))` solution would result in a skewed distribution if there were different possible numbers left and right of the excluded number.

Comment: If there is no way of storing the result of RANDBETWEEN in a variable and reusing it in the same expression  in excel, my solution of course is impossible to implement. My bad.