# Generate random string in text field

Tags: vba, ms-access

We have that old software (made by one of the first employees many years ago) in company that uses Microsoft Access to run. Boss asked me to add a random string generation in the specific text box on click but i have no idea how to do that. I dont have any Microsoft Access programming experience, thats why i am askin you to help.

I managed to create button and text field so far. Thats where it stops. I also managed to access the code for the button action:

```
Private Sub command133_Click()

End Sub
```

Comment: @Bathsheba letters and numbers, lets say 8 characters long

Comment: do you want lower and upper case letters? The answer I've given is for upper case letters only.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes also lower case letters + numbers if it is not too much work :)

Comment: I've amended: generates letters an numbers now

Comment: @Bathsheba Thank you :) Will try to understand how it works and learn something new, not just copy it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one way, will work in Access VBA (which is an older basic than vb.net). It will generate a string with letters and numbers.

```
Sub test()

    Dim s As String * 8 'fixed length string with 8 characters
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim ch As Integer 'the character
    For n = 1 To Len(s) 'don't hardcode the length twice
        Do
            ch = Rnd() * 127 'This could be more efficient.
            '48 is '0', 57 is '9', 65 is 'A', 90 is 'Z', 97 is 'a', 122 is 'z'.
        Loop While ch < 48 Or ch > 57 And ch < 65 Or ch > 90 And ch < 97 Or ch > 122
        Mid(s, n, 1) = Chr(ch) 'bit more efficient than concatenation
    Next

    Debug.Print s

End Sub
```

Comment: +1, as an alternative, I would use additional rand value to determine from which range genereate `ch`. Idea is from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22506271/randbetween1-11-but-not-6/22506324#22506324

Comment: Hi @Bathsheba, just a feedback. I test your code in Excel for random string 13 characters length. in 1million rows, excel create 13,826 duplicated strings and only 986,174 unique string left. It may be unique enough in most case, but I think there is a flaw in Rnd() function. In theory, a randomly select of 13 characters & number in group of 62 characters and number (0-9 a-z A-Z), there should be more than 8.3 billion unique selections. So 14k duplicate records in 1million records is quite significant. Any though? Thanks For your code.

Comment: Uniquely random is an entirely different requirement. You are correct, the *periodicity* of `Rnd()` is remarkably small.

Comment: Maybe you should add `Randomize` before the call to `Rnd()`

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
Public Function GetRandomString(ByVal iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim rdm As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 1 To iLength
        sResult &= ChrW(rdm.Next(32, 126))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

Comment: Q about _Access VBA_, but not _VB.NET_

Comment: Yes, but the tags were edited *after* this answer was submitted. It *would* work in vb.net, so +1.

Answer (score 1):

Workin on @Bathsheba code, I did this. It will generate a random string with the number of characters you'd like.

Code :

```
Public Function GenerateUniqueSequence(numberOfCharacters As Integer) As String

    Dim random As String  ' * 8 'fixed length string with 8 characters
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim ch As Integer   ' each character

    random = ""

    For j = 1 To numberOfCharacters
        random = random & GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter
    Next

    GenerateUniqueSequence = random

End Function

Public Function GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter() As String

    'Numbers : 48 is '0', 57  is '9'
    'LETTERS : 65 is 'A', 90  is 'Z'
    'letters : 97 is 'a', 122 is 'z'

    GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter = ""

    Dim i As Integer

    Randomize
    i = (Rnd() * 2) + 1 'One chance out of 3 to choose one of 3 catégories

    Randomize
    Select Case i
        Case 1 'Numbers
            GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter = Chr(Rnd() * 9 + 48)
        Case 2 'LETTERS
            GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter = Chr(Rnd() * 25 + 65)
        Case 3 'letters
            GenerateRandomAlphaNumericCharacter = Chr(Rnd() * 25 + 97)
    End Select

End Function
```

I use it with random number of characters, like this :

```
'Generates random Session ID between 15 and 30 alphanumeric characters
SessionID = GenerateUniqueSequence(Rnd * 15 + 15)
```

Result :

> s8a8qWOmoDvC4jKRjPr5hOY12u               26
>   TB24qZ4cNfr6EdyY0J             18
>   6LZRQ9P5WHLNd71LIdqJ           20
>   KPN0RmlhhJKnVzPTkW             18
>   R2pNOKWJMKl9KpSoIV2egUNTEb1QC2               30
>   X8jHuupP6SvEI8Dt2wJi           20

NOTE: This is still not completely random. It will give a higher count of numbers than normal as approx 1/3 of all chars generated will be numbers.

Normally distribution will look like:
10 numbers plus 26 lowercase plus 26 uppercase = 62 possible chars. 
Numbers will normally be 10/62 parts of the string or 1/6.2
With the code 
    i = (Rnd() * 2) + 1 'One chance out of 3 to choose one of 3 catégories
the count of numbers is pushed up to 1/3 (on average)

Probably not too much of a worry - unless you are trying to beat the NSA and then you have decreased your range significantly.