# VBA User-Defined type not defined

Tags: ms-access, vba

Trying to fix the recent "Scriptlet.TypeLib" problem and tried to follow a solution outlined here: [MS Access VBA Error: Run time error '70' Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332357/ms-access-vba-error-run-time-error-70-permission-denied#) in Access but I keep getting a "user-defined type not defined" error.

Comment: Which version of Access are you using?

Comment: And which line of the VBA is highlighted when you get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the code as posted in the other SO answer, and your compile error is occurring on this line,

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CoCreateGuid Lib "ole32.dll" (Guid As GUID_TYPE) As LongPtr
```

then it's likely because you're using an older version of Access (and a 6.x version of VBA), that is unaware of the `LongPtr` keyword. You should be able to just substitute `Long` for every instance of `LongPtr`.

Comment: I'm using access 2016. I'll give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks @thunderFrame, that worked.  Like I mentioned this was Access 2016 but I still had to change it from LongPtr to Long.  I don't know that I would have ever figured that out.  Thanks again.